# Specific definition of weak-star convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.01329.pdf) the authors recall the definition of weak$^{\star}$-convergence in the footnotes on page 2. The problem setting is as follows:

Let $(S, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space, where $S \neq \emptyset$, and $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $S$. Denote by $\Delta(S, \Sigma)$ the set of all probabilities (here in this case defined as additive capacity). Then, the statement is as follows:

A net $\{ P_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ converges to $P$ in the weak$^{\star}$-topology if and only if $P_{\alpha}(A) \longrightarrow P(A)$ for all $A \in \Sigma$.

How does this characterization fit the usual definition of convergence wrt to the weak$^{\star}$-topology from functional analysis? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Related [P1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4367716/121671), [P2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3815707/121671).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the space of all bounded measurable functions on $(S,\Sigma)$ with the sup norm. This is Banach space and any probability measure $P$  on $(S,\Sigma)$ can be considered as  an element of the dual space (via $f \mapsto \int f dP$). Convergence as defined here is precisely weak* convergence in $X^{*}$.

For a justification you have to note that any bounded measurable function is a uniform limit of simple functions.  [Some details are in my comment below].

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would expect that (let us assume for simplicity that we have sequences instead of nets) we have $P_n \rightarrow P$ (weak$^{\star}$) iff $\int f dP_n \rightarrow \int f dP$ for all bounded and measurable functions $f$. I do not understand why it is sufficient for the "iff" statement in the question to assume set wise convergence of the probability measures.

Comment: Suppose $P_{\alpha}(A) \to P(A)$ for every $A$. $\|f-g\|<\epsilon$ implies $|\int fdP_{\alpha}-\int gdP_{\alpha}| <\epsilon$ for every $\alpha$ and $|\int fdP-\int gdP| <\epsilon$. Also $\int gdP_{\alpha} \to \int gdP$. Now use triangle inequality to finish the proof of $\int f dP_{\alpha} \to \int fdP$.

Comment: This somehow would justify why $P_{\alpha}(A) \rightarrow P(A)$ for every $A$ implies that $\{P_{\alpha}\}$ converges to $P$ with respect to the weak$^{\star}$-topology, but why is the other direction "obvious"?

Comment: Ah, for the other direction we just say $f = 1_{A}$ for $A \in \Sigma$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. @Galois1763